# includes before the doctype

Tags: web, include, loading, config, doctype

should an include be placed before the DOCTYPE of a PHP file?

I have an include leading to a config file which i believe is preventing a website from loading. If remove this include the page loads (with errors as functions are missing) but as soon as i put it back in it breaks again.

Please note. I have a number of other sites with this include before the DOCTYPE that all work perfectly well. And the config file it they lead to are exactly identical which tells me its not the coding in the config file.

so the very top line now looks like this:

```
<? include('config.php'); ?><!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

the config file then looks like this:

```
 <?
// WEBSITE SETUP
$config_website_code = "FR"; // .net IS Q, EVERYTHING ELSE IS GEO CODE
$config_db_error = 1; // IS THE DATABASE WORKING? 0 IS NO
$config_website_url = "http://www.lektronix.fr";
$config_website_short_url = "lektronix.fr";

// GOOGLE ANALYTICS
$config_analytics_code = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n";
$config_analytics_code .= "var _gaq = _gaq || [];\n";
$config_analytics_code .= "_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-4257220-56']);\n";
$config_analytics_code .= "_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);\n";
$config_analytics_code .= "(function() {\n";
$config_analytics_code .= "var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;\n";
$config_analytics_code .= "ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';\n";
$config_analytics_code .= "var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);\n";
$config_analytics_code .= "})();\n";
$config_analytics_code .= "</script>\n";

// ASSIGN GEO BASED ON THEIR IP
include('assign_geo.php'); 

// ASSIGN THEIR LANGUAGE
include('assign_language.php'); 

// DEFINE THE CONTENT THEY SEE
include('assign_content.php');

// COMMON PAGE FUNCTIONS
include('functions.php'); 

// HEADER AND DESCRIPTION TAGS
include('assign_meta_data.php');  
?>
```

this is identical to other working websites and the files included within the config file are also identical.

i removed all content from the header and index files and just had echo "hello world";

this loaded and was correct.

i then began placing code back in but the first line i placed back in was the include before the doctype and this broke the website again.

Comment: if you can, please provide sample code and explain what configuration the PHP is modifying in your HTML

Comment: ok edited main post for you fizzy drink

Comment: if you are inserting elements such as `<script>` and `<meta>` before the !DOCTYPE, then it will fail. Anything relating to the HTML file (or tags that make up part of the HTML file) such as `<html><head>` etc. cannot go before the !DOCTYPE. If you are inserting PHP only or MySQL queries (server side) or SESSION related, those can go before the !DOCTYPE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can put PHP code before the DOCTYPE in a file it will not cause any problems. Looking at your code and from what you've told me the problem should be with your code in one of the files being called from the config file. My guess is the Functions file. go check that out. A little debugging will go a long way.